# gccでC言語のコンパイルができない

Tags: c

※Xcodeをインストールしています。

VSCodeのターミナルから `gcc -o main main.c` でコンパイルしようとしましたが以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_avg", referenced from:
  _main in main-d23be1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

use -v と書いてあるので `gcc -v main main.c` としたところ、以下のようになりました。エラーの解決方法を教えてください。

```
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'main'
```

#### ソースコード

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calc.h"

int main(){
  double d1,d2,d3;
  double a = 1.2,b = 3.4,c = 2.7;
  //   同じ計算が3回(関数を呼び出して計算）
  d1 = avg(a,b);
  d2 = avg(4.1,5.7);
  d3 = avg(c,2.8);
  printf("d1 = %f,d2 = %f,d3 = %f¥n",d1,d2,d3);
}
```

calc.h

```
#ifndef _CALC_H_
#define _CALC_H_

//  関数avgのプロトタイプ宣言
double avg(double,double);

#endif // _CALC_H_
```

calc.c

```
#include "calc.h"

//  平均値を求める関数
double avg(double l,double m){
    //  引数l,mの平均値を求め、rに代入する。
    double r = (l + m) / 2.0;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc -o main main.c calc.c` のように、`calc.c` もコマンドラインに指定してください。関数 `avg()` が `calc.c` の中にあるからです。

Answer (score 0):

分割コンパイルの解説は検索すればすぐ見つかると思うのだけど、一番簡単で遅いコンパイル・リンク手順は

```
gcc -o main main.c calc.c
```

なぜこうしないといけないかは、やはり検索してみて、それでもわからなければ別質問にしてくれると幸い。

他の方法だと `Makefile` を作って `make` するってことになるんだけど、全部解説すると分量が多いっス。